# How can I perform a super shoot in Hat Trick Hero 2?

Tags: hat-trick-hero-2

I am trying to figure out how to perform a super shoot in **Hat Trick Hero 2** for SNES. I need an explanation on how to do it and I researched, and no one has it.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could find was this, even GameFAQs doesn't have much:

> TAITO POWER GOAL / HAT TRICK HERO 95
>   - Buy hyper shoot or super shoot (push button 3 when you see 'press "C" button').
>   - Pass the ball using button 2. (you must do this one or more times).

Source: http://forum.arcadecontrols.com/index.php?topic=40337.0